# division of block element diagonally with responsiveness

Tags: html, css

I need to divide one box into two parts, diagonally from top-left corner to bottom-right corner. The lower part is just to have a shadow of another color.

I tried and got the requirement with values in the demo. But not responsive.
The photoContainer-div width is 100% so it is responsive. Now the problem occurred. I did solution for a specific width of photo container only. But, I need the requirement in responsiveness.

```css
.photo-container {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  height: 285px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
.shade {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
.shade:before {
  content: "";
  width: 125%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  background-color: #ff0;
  opacity: 0.3;
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotate(14.45deg);
  top: 40%;
  left: -24%
}
```

```html
<div class="photo-container">
  <div class="shade"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Background-image linear-gradient has this posibility. You need to use the *to corner* syntax

```css
.photo-container {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  height: 285px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}
.shade {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top right, yellow 50%, transparent 50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="photo-container">
  <div class="shade"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. This is what I want @vals